# How can I use JavaScript between different html components?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

[The components are these.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjmoD.png)

My function in JavaScript is this:

```
function render(){
    for (let index=1; index <=6; index++){
      nintendoDIV.innerHTML+=`${HTMLnintendoProduct(index)}`;
      pcDIV.innerHTML+=`${HTMLpcProduct(index)}`;
      playDIV.innerHTML+=`${HTMLplayProduct(index)}`;
      xboxDIV.innerHTML+=`${HTMLxboxProduct(index)}`;
    }
```

In the index, I have placed it in the body to call it.

```
**<body onload="render()">**

  <app-root></app-root>

<script src="assets/js/prod.js"></script>

</body>
```

In my home.component.html I have the following

```
<div class="container marketin">
     <br>
     
     <h2 id="nintendo">Nintendo</h2>
     <hr>
     <div class="row" id="nintendoDIV"></div>

     <h2 id="pc">PC</h2>
     <hr>
     <div class="row" id="pcDIV"></div>

     <h2 id="play">PlayStation</h2>
     <hr>
     <div class="row" id="playDIV"></div>

     <h2 id="xbox">Xbox</h2>
     <hr>
     <div class="row" id="xboxDIV"></div>
     <p class="float-right container">
      <a class="text-success" href="#">ARRIBA</a>
    </p>
     <hr class="featurette-divider">
   </div>
```

[The products of that function should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvMBO.png)

Comment: where are all those variables (`nintendoDIV` etc) and functions (`HTMLnintendoProduct` etc) declared? the error clearly states that you are trying to access `.innerHTML` of `null` ... so one (or all) of those variables is `null`

Comment: @Bravo nintendoDIV and the others are in the home.component, the functions are in the same js that I use for function render (), which I call in the index: <script src = "assets / js / prod.js"> </script>

Comment: If you have to call a function in index, the function should be in ts file of index.html. You could call the function in home component.